# how to decode data from api to base64 in .html file using ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, decode, decodeuricomponent

i'm trying to view inside page.html file some data comes from API and this data is only long text encode via base64 , well the problem is i want to decode the text inside html file not at page.ts file so i tried many logic for that but nothing works with me .
example inside HTML file:

- {{item.text|| base64}}
- {{item.text|| decodeURIComponent}}
- {{item.text|| atob}}
- atob({{item.text}})

but nothing works . 
inside TS page i tried to use 
decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(ielement.text)))
and it's working but i want from html page

this is the text comes from API :
aGVsbG8gd29ybGQh

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Angular Pipe for decode base64 string like below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Usage:
 *   value | decodeBase64
 * Example:
 *   {{ 'aGFyZXNo' | decodeBase64 }}
 *
*/
@Pipe({name: 'decodeBase64'})
export class DecodeBase64Pipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {

    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)));
  }
}
```

and use this pipe as below in your HTML:

```
<p>Decoded text: {{'aGFyZXNo' | decodeBase64}}</p>
```

You need to add Pipe in you app.module file to register.

Comment: thank you so much , this is good way to do the correct logic but i get one error message,
https://i.imgur.com/fRgH6gN.png

https://i.imgur.com/4PtL4Xx.png

and this mean i have to declare escape and i do like that :
#declare function escape(s: string): string;
and after that  i get one more message 
https://i.imgur.com/AZQvXxo.png

thanks in advance

Comment: the issue is fixed by edit "return" of class DecodeBase64Pipe 

old code :
return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)));

new one :
 return decodeURIComponent(atob(value).split('').map(function (c) {
      return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));